# .load method takes too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm doing is loading different content into a div each button. The code I'm using to do so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#galleries').hide().load("letters/index.php", function(){
        $(this).slideDown(1);
        $(this).slideUp(1);  
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).slideDown(1500);/* or fadeIn() or any other effect*/
        document.getElementById("data").style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

This is an example of one code. I got another 8 like this, but I'm loading into #galleries a different php page everytime.

My problem is, it takes ages to load the second page. For example, on my first click on any button, it takes a second to load everything, doesn't matter what content it has. But whenever I press on another button to load another page, I have to wait for about 3-5seconds, and when I'm waiting, it shows nothing, no div is being shown, just the background.

Is it possible to fix this? Or maybe, is it possible inserting an LOADING image or text to let the user know that it's loading? so while the page is being loaded, the user sees : "LOADING.." or some loading icon.

Comment: Likely the problem is with the server, not the JavaScript. To make a LOADING notice, just show that image/div/whatever on click and hide it in the success callback.

Comment: why are you mixing plain js selectors (or: get element by id) and jquery's?

Comment: How long do you need to wait when you call your pages directly through the address bar of your browser?

Comment: None, the pages works great.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction.

Also I don't know what's with all of the different effects you have on `$(this)` either.

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".loading-image").show();

     $('#galleries').hide().load("letters/index.php", function(){
          $(this).slideDown(1);
          $(this).slideUp(1);    
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).slideDown(1500);/* or fadeIn() or any other effect*/

          $("#data").hide(); //replacing your getElementById


          $(".loading-image").hide();

      });

});
```

Comment: I got all of this $(this) because I got a problem that the Div can't predict the content height, therefore, it Just slides down for 50px and then just show all of the content. To solve that, I slided down the div + slided up, and then I could do the full animation. 
I will try your code :) thanks!

Comment: Well, couldn't make the .loading-image. I added a div with the loading image in it, and set the display to none, but still, it doesn't seem to work :O

Comment: did you give the div a class of "loading-image"? `<div class='loading-image'></div>`

Comment: yup. this is what I did:

<div class="loading-image" style="background-image:url('images/ajax_loader.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;display:none;"></div>
<div class="loading-image" style="background-image:url('images/ajax_loader.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;display:none;"></div>

Comment: Oh, you have the image as a background. Well you need to give the div a height and width in that case because the div doesn't automatically adjust to background sizes. So give the div the width and height of the loading image.

Comment: Yea, I accidently forgot to post it aswell >.< well, what it does now, it shows the image for about 0.1 seconds and then the image disapears but the text still doesn't apear. After I wait for another 2-3seconds, the text seems to apear. :( 
Can I somehow make the WHOLE page dark, and in the middle a picture of the loading for a limited period of time? for example, when the user changes content, it's gonna set the whole page DARK and disable any click ability, and show the LOADING image for 5seconds and then everything goes back normal with the new content?

Comment: Well you can do that. But is the loading image inside the `#galleries`? If so then since you hide that element then it would hide the loading image as well.

Comment: the CLASS isn't inside the Div. It's just above the DIV. I have already thought about that it's gonna hide it aswell

Comment: May you help me with my idea :o?

Comment: That's not too difficult of a task, but it would be too much to do on here.